# Why my Element not in view when page scrolls by itself in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Now, suppose my page have 10 clickable links with same class, one below another at some distance, such that only 1st 3 links are shown in current view, others are seen when i scroll down. Now, i have written a code to click on all of them. It clicks on first 3 and then selenium scrolls my page to show link 5 to 7, page is scrolling too much so as not to show link 4 and since code is trying to click link 4 which is not visible, my code gives error- Element is not visible.

Code:

```
def AddConnection(self):
        mylist=self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='primary-action-button label']")
        for x in mylist:
            x.click()
```

Full Error:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________________ test_add_connection _____________________________

driver = <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="3a05990c-13b
-4418-baee-f0d54c611ff7")>

>       add.AddConnection()

test_add_connection.py:22:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
PageSearchResults.py:24: in AddConnection
    x.click()
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:73: in cl
ck
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:456: in _
xecute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:236: in ex
cute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x01E6ACB
>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"name":"clickElement","sessionId":"3a0599
c-13b8-4418-baee-f0d54c611ff7","status":13,"value...int (892.5, 12.199996948242
88). Other element would receive the click: <div class=\"advanced-search-inner\
></div>"}'}

    def check_response(self, response):
        """
            Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an err
r.

            :Args:
             - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dict
onary
               object.

            :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
            """
        status = response.get('status', None)
        if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return

        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get('value', None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
                import json
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    status = value.get('error', None)
                    if status is None:
                        status = value["status"]
                        message = value["value"]
                        if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                            value = message
                            try:
                                message = message['message']
                            except TypeError:
                                message = None
                    else:
                        message = value.get('message', None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if value == '' or value is None:
            value = response['value']
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
                raise exception_class(response, value)
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and 'message' in value:
            message = value['message']

        screen = None
        if 'screen' in value:
            screen = value['screen']

        stacktrace = None
        if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
            stacktrace = []
            try:
                for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                    line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                    file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymou
>')
                    if line:
                        file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                    meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonym
us>')
                    if 'className' in frame:
                        meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                    msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                    msg = msg % (meth, file)
                    stacktrace.append(msg)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in
alue:
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].g
t('text'))
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (892.5,
2.199996948242188). Other element would receive the click: <div class="advanced
search-inner"></div>

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:194: We
DriverException
========================== 1 failed in 40.13 seconds ==========================
```

Comment: I don't think Selenium cares if the element is present within the visible window contents.  "Not visible" typically means that while the element is present in the html, it has been styled to appear invisible.

Comment: The error traceback you just posted has the error `WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable`.  This is different than the error you mention at the top of your post.  What are you really asking?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution, by adding this code after every click.

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 150);")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `x.location_once_scrolled_into_view` before you do x.click(). That should cause the element to scroll into view to be clicked.